# RKManagedObjectRequestOperation vs RKObjectRequestOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

A request operation can be of two types:

**RKManagedObjectRequestOperation :**  As mentioned in the doc

> `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` does NOT support object mapping that
>   targets an `NSManagedObjectContext` with a `concurrencyType` of
>   `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`

But I have used this to create request whose response map value to core data NSManagedObject model class without any problems.

**RKObjectRequestOperation :**

I have used this to create request whose response map value to normal model class.

So, what is the exact difference between RKManagedObjectRequestOperation and RKObjectRequestOperation and what is their proper implementation scenarios?

Comment: Ones for managed objects and the other isn't, I don't really get what you're asking...